# What must I add/remove to make this button the same size as the input field?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a basic landing page and I am adding a small newsletter signup component. When adding the bootstrap input group template, the button comes out much larger than the input field.

This is the code so far:

```
<!-- Newsletter -->
<section class="bg-primary text-light p-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <h3 class="mb-3 mb-md-0">Sign up for our Newsletter</h3>

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" type="button">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This is the specific input group code:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" type="button">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Remove `btn-lg` class on button

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adjust the input field by adding a height on it. Like below

```css
input.form-control {height: 38px}
```

```html
<!-- Newsletter -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section class="bg-primary text-light p-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <h3 class="mb-3 mb-md-0">Sign up for our Newsletter</h3>

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-dark " type="button">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do anything wrong. You either have to drop **btn-lg** class on the button or add **input-group-lg** alongside with **input-group** class. Both solutions are valid

here is an example of both solutions:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h2>Large form input</h2>
<section class="bg-primary text-light p-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <h3 class="mb-3 mb-md-0">Sign up for our Newsletter</h3>

      <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" type="button">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<h2 class="mt-5">Small form input</h2>
<section class="bg-primary text-light p-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <h3 class="mb-3 mb-md-0">Sign up for our Newsletter</h3>

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```